# How to forcefully install older version of jdk?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I'm unable to force an older installation (1 version ago) that is required by another app on Ubuntu 16.04.  Is there a way to force the install?

```
me@vm:/usr/lib/jvm$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'oracle-java8-installer' instead of 'openjdk-7-jdk'
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u181-1~webupd8~1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

me@vm:~$ sudo apt-get install -f openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'oracle-java8-installer' instead of 'openjdk-7-jdk'
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u181-1~webupd8~1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get -f install openjdk-7-jdk`?

Comment: Yes, it gets me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if openjdk-7-jdk is available in the repos? If not, you should add a repo that has available openjdk-7 or install it manually through .tar.gz